# PHP redirect not working when receiving a redirect URL

Tags: php, redirect

So I have the code below, and it does the following:

1. request a key via a curl command
2. the key is then send back to another URL -
3. this command then returns a URL which I am trying to redirect too.

When it attempts to redirect, I get the following error : Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected in C:\xampp\htdocs\blahblah\testapi.php on line 50

var_dump returns: string(39372) "https://pay.testdomain.com/eft?payment_key=0b1f024ccac63c7ce19ffad8b53a8d32"

```
<?php
ob_start();

#Get key
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'http://pay.testdomain.com/api/login-admin',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('email' => 'user@user.com','password' => 'mypassword'),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Accept: application/json'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$data = json_decode($response,true);
$key =  $data['data']['token'];


#Get redirect URL
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'http://pay.testdomain.com/api/payment-redir',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('amount' => '100.5555','merchant_ref' => '2222','payment_method' => 'eft'),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $key
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

header("Location: " . $response );  
exit;
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: _'var_dump returns: `string(39372) "https://pay.testdomain.com/eft?payment_key=0b1f024ccac63c7ce19ffad8b53a8d32"`'_ - that reported length seems a _bit_ off, for such a value, does it not? Try and apply `htmlspecialchars` before you dump it, in case there is any HTML code contained in there.

Comment: why `ob_start();` ? you are just going to redirect anyway

Comment: @CBroe  you sir / ma'am , are a lifesaver - saved me a lot of frustration  and grey hairs - really appreciate that , thank you.